# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fineUploaderS3 is not a function

Tags: fine-uploader

Trying to replicate the serverless s3 demo using my S3 static website.

I get index.html served from my S3 static website but using the Login with Amazon button I get a pop-up:

```
We're sorry!
An error occurred when we tried to process your request. Rest assured, we're already working on the problem and expect to resolve it shortly.
```

Looking at the console I see:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fineUploaderS3 is not a function"
```

My settings:

```
fineuploader.js var bucketUrl = "my S3 endpoint"
amazon-auth.js amazon.Login.setClientId("my app's ClientID")
```

Have app arn, role and policy setup for the app and S3 as per the blog.

These names were adjusted to the names from 5.3.2 download:

```
<link href="fine-uploader.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="all.fine-uploader.min.js"></script>
<script src="fineuploader-glue.js"></script>
```

Any ideas? I am very excited to use this product.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ray Nicholus solved my porblem but I guess I dont have enough rep points to accept the answer lol.  Love tech.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message, you are utilizing jQuery on your page, but are not actually pulling the jQuery library in. If you *must* use jQuery, you'll need to ensure it is imported in the `<head>` tag of your page.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.  Now its says 400 Bad Request
Unknown client_id.  I am trying to use a separate app console account and S3 account so that may be the problem but I do specify the app_id from the app account in the trust relationship for the S3 role so I would think it would work.  I am going to move everything under the same roof to simplify things.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am having trouble bc my s3 is not https so I cannot white list it.  Can you tell me how you setup https://fineuploader-s3-client-demo.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?